# 'str' object has no attribute 'get', AttributeError at /add-to-cart/shirt

Tags: python, django

I am getting above stated error after lining some modification in models and views and here are the associated code:

```
def add_to_cart(request, slug):
    item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
    order_item, created = OrderedItems.objects.get_or_create(
        item=item,
        user=request.user,
        ordered=False
    )
    order_qs = Order.objects.filter(user=request.user, ordered=False)
    if order_qs.exists():
        order = order_qs[0]
        # check if the order item is in the order
        if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
            order_item.quantity += 1
            order_item.save()
            messages.info(request, "This item quantity was updated.")
            return reverse('core:product_detail', kwargs={'slug': slug})
        else:
            order.items.add(order_item)
            messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
            return reverse('core:product_detail', kwargs={'slug': slug})
    else:
        ordered_date = timezone.now()
        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=request.user, ordered_date=ordered_date)
        order.items.add(order_item)
        messages.info(request, "This item was added to your cart.")
        return reverse('core:product_detail', kwargs={'slug': slug})
```

the trace back seems to be really vague:

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\ecommerce_only-Npoh1MB8\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\ecommerce_only-Npoh1MB8\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py" in __call__
  96.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "C:\Users\pytuts\.virtualenvs\ecommerce_only-Npoh1MB8\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py" in process_response
  26.         if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /add-to-cart/shirt/
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

and urls.py looks like:

```
path('add-to-cart/<slug:slug>/', add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `reverse(...)` returns a string, which is the url for a certain name. But you need return a [**`Http response`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/) from the view, like for example [**`HttpResponseRedirect`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect):

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
...

return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core:product_detail', kwargs={'slug': slug}))
```

Comment: thank you this is it, we can use redirect as well I guess